# How to access video stream from an wyze camera using opencv in python from google cloud function?

Tags: opencv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access wyze camera from google cloud function but its not working

Currently we cannot access wyze camera via web browser. So i researched a bit and found that Tinycam Pro app can be used to achieve it. I added the wyze camera to that app followed the steps and enabled its web server for remote access. Then i got an url like this - http://ip-address:8083.

[image]
If i access that link it took me to the webserver page, then i logged in and clicked on the 'All cameras' button, navigated to page where my camera is available to see the live video stream from wyze camera. 
But i wasn't able to see it outside of my network.

So i did port forwarding. logged into my router and added rule with the below details :

public port - 8083 .
private port - 8083 .
protocol - TCP .
gave local ip address

After this i was able to access the webserver page from outside my network and click the 'All cameras' button, navigated to page where my camera is available to see the live video stream from wyze camera

When i try to access it in cloud function its not working

```
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://username:password@public ip address:8083/live?cameraId=102698986")
   result, image = cap.read()
   print(result)
```

Please advice.

Comment: And the error message is what?

Comment: Am trying to print the result once i read the videocapture(url).The result is false always. Its not able to capture image from the video url